# Как удалить элемент списка из середины list?

Tags: c++

Добрый день, у меня такой вопрос: я определяю свой тип данных

```
typedef struct {    
    string name;   
    string avtor;   
    string place; /* и т.д. */    
} librery;
```

Создаю список

```
list< librery> bibl;
```

Заполняю его значениями, мне нужно найти элемент (или все элементы) в списке, предположим по полю name, и удалить их. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
struct NameEqualTo {
    NameEqualTo(const std::string& name) : name_(name) {}
    bool operator()(const librery& l) const {return l.name == name_;}
    std::string name_;
};

bibl.remove_if(NameEqualTo("John"));
```

Если использовать boost, то можно короче написать:

```
bibl.remove_if(boost::bind(&librery::name, _1) == "John");
```

Можно просто ручками поудалять:

```
for (std::list<librer>::iterator it = bibl.begin(); it != bibl.end();) {
    if (it->name == "John") {
        it = bibl.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```